# Kdb/q : write a function that keeps taking the head of a list, and return value to end of the list

Tags: kdb

I want to maintain a list `L`. So I want to write a function `func[]` that always take the last table of list `L`, work on it, return a value that appends to the end of `L`.

For example:

Let `L` be `[a,b,c]`

`func()` will take `c`, compute `d = func[c]`

Now `L` becomes `[a,b,c,d]`

`func()` will take `d`, compute `e = func[d]`

Now `L` becomes `[a,b,c,d,e]`

Et cetera.

How can I implement this in kdb/q?

Answer (score 4):

Do or while should allow you to achieve this e.g.

```
q)l:0 2;f:{x,2*last x}
q)
q)5 f/ l           // do op 5 times
0 2 4 8 16 32 64
q)
q)(64>last@) f/ l  // perform op while last item in list is less than 64
0 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the *over* function is what you need.
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/over/

```
q)l:1 2 3
q)f:{if[100<count x;:x];x,1+last x}
q)over[f;l]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29..
```

I added a condition to break the loop in f. When using over if the same result is returned twice it will stop.

You could also use .z.s. This will repeat the current function with new input.
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zs-self

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @CWD's answer, you could do this with explicit recursion using `.z.s` like so:

```
func: {[x;f;threshold] $[threshold <= count x;x;.z.s [x,enlist f last x;f;threshold]]}
func[1 2 3;{x*10};5} /returns 1 2 3 30 300
```

This will recursively apply your function to the last element until the total count of the list hits your specified threshold. Of course, set the threshold too high, and you will end up with a `stack` error. As such, it is preferable to use the standard iterators in production-grade code.